# Using object variable as a recursive method argument in a Python class

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function within a class, but have some trouble using an object var as a method argument:

```
class nonsense(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  def factorial(self, n=self.val):
    if n<=1: return 1
    return n*self.factorial(n=n-1)
```

The code above generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in nonsense
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

But if I don't refer to self.val, the error disappears, although having to specify n is redundant:

```
class nonsense(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  def factorial(self, n):
    if n<=1: return 1
    return n*self.factorial(n=n-1)
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, you cannot have `self.xxx` in the header -- rather have None and then correct in the body:

```
def factorial(self, n=None):
    if n is None: n = self.val
    if n<=1: return 1
    return n*self.factorial(n=n-1)
```

The reason is that when the class object is being created there is no `self`; besides `globals()`, the only names defined when Python gets to `factorial` are `__module__`, and `__init__`.

As an experiment to prove this to yourself, try this:

```
class TestClassCreation(object):
    print("Started creating class")
    print("names so far: %s" % vars())

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    print("now we have %s" % vars())

    def noop(self, default=None):
        print("this gets run when noop is called")
    print("and now have %s" % vars())
    print()

    print("and now we'll fail...")
    def failure(self, some_arg=self.noop):
        pass
    print("we never get here...")
```

Answer (score 6):

Default parameters are evaluated when the method is defined. Thus, it's essentially "too late" to use a member value defined in `__init__`. What you should do is set the default value to `None` and test for this in the body of the function:

```
class nonsense(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def factorial(self, n=None):
        if n is None:
            n = self.val
        elif n <= 1:
            return 1

        return n*self.factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the strange behavior is that the `def` statement only gets executed once, when the function is defined. Thus the initializer value only gets created once, at a time when there isn't yet a `self` reference.

As an alternative, try this:

```
class nonsense(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  def factorial(self, n=None):
    return self.factorial_aux(n if n is not None else self.val)
  def factorial_aux(self, n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * self.factorial(n-1)
```

The above solution only tests once if the `n` parameter has the default value (`None`) and after that, it returns the result of calling `factorial_aux` (which does the actual work) with the appropriate argument.

Answer (score 0):

why not write is simply as this?

```
class fact1():  
    def fact2(self, num):
        if num==1:
            return 1
        ss=num*self.fact2(num-1)
        return ss

exx=fact1()
print exx.fact2(5)
```

Output 120

Comment: Because this isn't simple and clear.  Compare `fact(5)` vs `fact1().fact2(5)`.